# undefined offset even though it's defined

Tags: php, undefined, offset

```
$a = array("rob", "kate", "alex", "nick");
$q = (isset($_REQUEST["q"]) ? $_REQUEST["q"] : null);
$arr =  explode(".", $q);

$output = array();
foreach ($a as &$value) {
    if (substr($value, 0, strlen($arr[1])) === $arr[1])
```

I get an undefined offset error inside this part of the code:

```
($arr[1])) === $arr[1])
```

Both the `$arr[1]`'s, even though I have defined them.

Why do I still get this message?

**Error Message:**

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in D:\domain.php on line 10

Comment: Show us the dumped contents of `$arr` and `$q`.

Comment: @koeneman but it says "Notice" and not "Error"...?

Comment: @Script47 not sure :-D just wondering... I thought notices are no problem to run the code...

Comment: what is your querystring? `?q=....`?

Comment: @zypro so putting a '@' in front of the $arr wil not cause a problem?

Comment: @koeneman that will not fix your issue and is a terrible idea. `@` just suppresses the error. A notice by definition is trying to get your attention to notify you because something is not working right. Your best bet would be to fix the issue, not mask it, or  hide it. To start, please can you provide the dumped information (`var_dump` / `print_r`) that I requested above.

Comment: Your probleme is that `$_REQUEST["q"]` seems not to be set. You're running `explode` on `null` so later on the index `1` is not defined.

Comment: @Script47 no, everything works only the message is still shown, so that`s weird.

Comment: @koeneman I'm assuming that is the dump for `$arr`? If so, that is your issue. `$arr[1]` is ***not*** set which means that the notice is in fact correct.

Comment: @Script47 Sorry it`s not that, its: array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" }

Comment: @koeneman what is inside of `$_REQUEST["q"]`?

Comment: @DamianDziaduch "q" is like all what you type in.

Comment: If the dump of ``$arr`` is ``array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" }`` then referencing ``$arr[1]`` would give you an "undefined offset" error because only ``$arr[0]`` exists, not ``$arr[1]``.

Comment: @kmoser okay okay, so what do I have to do to make it exist because it should exist right? I have used explode.

Comment: '*so what do I have to do to make it exist because it should exist right?*' - We don't honestly know whether it should exist or not because we don't know what this script / app is supposed to do (I'm not saying we need to know because questions should be self-contained).

Comment: If your code does what it's supposed to do, and all you want to do is get rid of the notice, then use @ to suppress it. But since I don't really know what your script is supposed to be doing, it can't make a blanket recommendation to use @ to suppress the notice.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the `$arr` is an array before using it

```
$a = array("rob", "kate", "alex", "nick");
$q = (isset($_REQUEST["q"]) ? $_REQUEST["q"] : null);
$arr =  explode(".", $q);

$output = array();
foreach ($a as &$value) {
    if (isset($arr[1]) && substr($value, 0, strlen($arr[1])) === $arr[1]);
```

Comment: Would it not be better to break out of the loop the first time if `$arr[1]` is not set? That way you aren't pointlessly continuing the loop even though it will never execute any of the code.